# editable text flutter on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter. I want to make the text editable but it show some error. Am I doing it right? Below show the design I want. I hope someone can also explain to me briefly. Thank you so much!

[image]

```
class EditNameEmail extends StatefulWidget {

  bool _isEnable = false; //_isEnable is the boolean variable and set it false, so we have to make it true when user tap on text
  TextEditingController _controller =
  TextEditingController(text: 'Wong Yuk Hei'); 

  @override
  State<EditNameEmail> createState() => _EditNameEmailState();
}

class _EditNameEmailState extends State<EditNameEmail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0), 
      child: Column( 
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [ 
          Text('Name', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),),
          Row( 
            children: <Widget> [
              Container( 
                child: TextField( 
                  controller: _controller,
                  enabled: _isEnable,
                ),
              ), 
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit), 
                onPressed: () { 
                  setState (() => { 
                    _isEnable = true;
                  });
                }),
              
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move `_isEnable` and `_controller` to the `_EditNameEmailState` class. Because the widget is immutable, you need to place state values in the state class.

Second, use the `Expanded` widget. See the [Unbounded hight - Flutter channel](https://youtu.be/jckqXR5CrPI) for more info.

Third, the lambda function doesn't use an arrow(`=>`) if you use the code block(`(){}`).

**Do Not**

```dart
() => {}
```

**Do**

```dart
() {}
// or
() => someReturnValue
```

#### Full code

The complete code is here.

```dart
class EditNameEmail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<EditNameEmail> createState() => _EditNameEmailState();
}

class _EditNameEmailState extends State<EditNameEmail> {
  bool _isEnable = false; //_isEnable is the boolean variable and set it false, so we have to make it true when user tap on text
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: 'Wong Yuk Hei');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget> [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  enabled: _isEnable,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState (() {
                      _isEnable = true;
                    });
                  }),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```